# Updating header hiding javascript to work with jQuery 3.6.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I’m updating a website that was running jQuery 2.1.3 and is now on jQuery 3.6.4.

We’ve been using the code below to:

- Hide the header navigation when the user scrolls past the height of the header
- On pages with a parallax banner, hide the header once the user has scrolled past the banner (hence the class .para-scroll)
- Show the header when the user scrolls up
- Show the header when the user scroll to the very bottom of the page

It has worked perfectly with former versions of jQuery but it unfortunately won’t fire on 3.6.4.

I’m wondering if there’s a part of the code or a specific parameter that’s no longer compatible?

```
// Hide Header on scroll down
$(function(){   
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('#header').outerHeight();
var parallaxHeight = $('.homeSlide, .who-slide').outerHeight();

$(window).on('scroll', function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;
    
    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
        if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight) {
             $('#header.scroll').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
        }
        if (st > lastScrollTop && st > parallaxHeight+10){
        // Scroll Down
            $('#header.para-scroll').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
        } 
        else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('#header.scroll, #header.para-scroll').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
        }
 
    }
    
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
        $('#header.scroll, #header.para-scroll').css({'top' : 0});
   }
   else {
        $('#header.scroll, #header.para-scroll').removeAttr("style");
   }
});
});
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Are there any messages on the browser console?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].